# How to define a literal object to store different properties with generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to store some react components in a literal object. And these components' props are different.

```
interface ComponentMap<P = any> {
  [key: string]: React.JSXElementConstructor<P>
}

const cMap: ComponentMap = {}

interface AProps {
  str: string
}

interface BProps {
  n: number
}

cMap['a'] = (props: AProps) => { /* code */ }
cMap['b'] = (props: BProps) => { /* code */ }
// there may be c, d, e and other components assigned into cMap
```

Currently I use `<P = any>` to avoid type errors. But when I get a component from `cMap`, its props type is also `any`.

```
const CompA = cMap['a']
const CompB = cMap['b']

<CompA /> 
<CompB />
// no type errors
```

Is there any way to keep the props' type of `CompA/B`? How to correctly define `ComponentMap`?
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Prefer a `Record` in this case, and a `React.ComponentType<P>`:
`type ComponentMap = Record<string, React.ComponentType<AProps | BProps>>`.
Thing is that Typescript will raise an error when you will render the component as it will be unable to determinate if it's a `React.ComponentType<AProps>` or a `React.ComponentType<BProps`>. Therefore you may need to encapsulate this component with an object that help typescript to determine which object is used.
For instance : `Record<string, { type: 'CompA', comp: React.ComponentType<AProps> } | {type: 'CompB', comp: React.ComponentType<BProps> }>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry, I didn't make it clear. `CompA` & `CompB` are examples, more unknown components will be assigned into `cMap` dynamically. Is there a better way besides using `|`?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a situation where you want to enforce that a variable `extends` a particular type without widening the type of that variable, then you need to create the variable through a function.

```
type BaseMap = Record<string, ComponentType<any>;

const createComponentMap = <M extends BaseMap>(map: M): M => map;

const cMap = createComponentMap({
  a: (props: AProps) => { /* code */ return null; },
  b: (props: BProps) => { /* code */ return null; }
})

const ComponentA = cMap.a;

<ComponentA str="a"/> // ok
<ComponentA/> // error: Property 'str' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'AProps'
```

---

> more unknown components will be assigned into cMap dynamically

This part makes it more interesting.  You could create something fancy here where the map had methods to add new objects.  The simple solution is just to create a new map object whenever you add anything because you always want to change the type of the map.  Here's how we can add a third component `c`:

```
const nextMap = createComponentMap({
  ...cMap,
  c: (props: CProps) => { /* code */ return null; }
});
```

---

Here's how it works with the chaining approach.  It's easier for the `add` function to take an object like `{c: ComponentC}` than separate key and value arguments.

```
interface ComponentMap<M extends BaseMap> {
  map: M;
  add<T extends BaseMap>(added: T): ComponentMap<M & T>;
  get<K extends keyof M>(key: K): M[K];
}

const createComponentMap = <M extends BaseMap>(map: M): ComponentMap<M> => ({
  map,
  add<T extends BaseMap>(added: T): ComponentMap<M & T> {
    return createComponentMap({
      ...map,
      ...added
    })
  },
  get<K extends keyof M>(key: K): M[K] {
    return map[key];
  }
});

const cMap = createComponentMap({
  a: (props: AProps) => { /* code */ return null; },
  b: (props: BProps) => { /* code */ return null; }
})

const ComponentA = cMap.get('a') // or cMap.map.a;

const nextMap = cMap.add({
  c: (props: CProps) => { /* code */ return null; }
});
```

---

Here's how it works with the `key` and `component` as separate arguments:

```
interface ComponentMap<M extends BaseMap> {
  map: M;
  add<K extends string, C extends ComponentType<any>>(key: K, component: C): ComponentMap<M & Record<K, C>>;
  get<K extends keyof M>(key: K): M[K];
}

const createComponentMap = <M extends BaseMap>(map: M): ComponentMap<M> => ({
  map,
  add<K extends string, C extends ComponentType<any>>(key: K, component: C): ComponentMap<M & Record<K, C>> {
    return createComponentMap({
      ...map,
      [key]: component
    })
  },
  get<K extends keyof M>(key: K): M[K] {
    return map[key];
  }
});

const cMap = createComponentMap({})
  .add("a", (props: AProps) => { /* code */ return null; })
  .add("b", (props: BProps) => { /* code */ return null; })
  .add("c", (props: CProps) => { /* code */ return null; });
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! Is this a common case to expand an interface dynamically in Typescript? Generics are hard for me to understand :(