# Declare TypeScript type while inferring some part of that type

Tags: typescript

Imagine you have multiple modules and you want each one to export an object of some specific shape. At the same time, the object’s properties may have variable types that you want to infer when the modules are imported. Is there a way to declare the object’s type (so you have autocompletion when writing the object), but also be able to infer a specific object’s property types?

Here's an example that obviously doesn't work since we're explicitly setting the type to be inferred:

```js
type MyObject<T> = { myProp: T }

// moduleA.ts
export const a: MyObject<any> = ({ myProp: 42 });

// moduleB.ts
export const b: MyObject<any> = ({ myProp: "A string" });

// index.ts
import { a } from "./moduleA";
import { b } from "./moduleB";

const objectMap = { a, b };

type ObjectMap = typeof objectMap

type InferredMap = {
 [P in keyof ObjectMap]: ObjectMap[P] extends { myProp: infer R } ? R : unknown
}
```

The resulting type is unsurprisingly `{ a: any, b: any }`.

How do we make this `{ a: number, b: string }` while still keeping the autocomplete when writing the module?

I understand that if I avoid explicitly providing the types for `a` and `b`, these will be inferred. But then I lose autocompletion when writing the module (i.e. I can't start typing `m` and see that `myProp` is a valid property).

Similarly, I don't want to require the user to explicitly provide a type to `MyObject`. In this example, it's just a `number` or `string`, but in reality this type could ve very complex and it's not something I want the user to have to explicitly write out when they are already writing out the actual values that determine the type.

Moreover, I understand I could do this with a single module and a function, for example:

```
type MappedType<
  T extends { [key: string]: { myProp: any } }
> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends { myProp: infer R } ? R : unknown
}

function getResult<T extends { [key: string]: { myProp: any } }> (map: T): MappedType<T> {
  //
}
```

But the question is how to achieve the same result across module boundaries?

Comment: The trick is that you need to create your object through a function.  It’s basically the same as this answer I wrote a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221364/10431574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: See update below the divider.

The entire type of both `a` and `b` can be inferred, you don't need a type declaration on them at all.

```typescript
// moduleA.ts
export const a = { myProp: 42 };

// moduleB.ts
export const b = { myProp: "A string" };

// index.ts
import { a } from "./moduleA";
import { b } from "./moduleB";

const objectMap = { a, b };
```

The type of `objectMap` will be

```typescript
{
    a: {
        myProp: number;
    };
    b: {
        myProp: string;
    };
}
```

The `a` and `b` properties on that are compatible with `MyObject<T>`, since TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal. It doesn't matter what the type's *name* is, what matters is the shape it defines.

With the above, you get autocomplete information (at least in VSCode and the TypeScript playground):

[image: TypeScript playground showing inference on objectMap.a with myProp of type number]

Alternatively, you can put the type on them if you like by giving the type of the property rather than `any`:

```typescript
export const a: MyObject<number> = { myProp: 42 };
```

---

In a comment you've clarified that it's not where you're using `objectMap` where you want autocomplete, it's where you're defining `a` and `b`. Sorry for misunderstanding that.

That's very similar to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003094/can-you-make-ts-infer-a-variables-generic-type-arguments-from-those-on-the-valu). As far as I know, you can only do that with a function:

```typescript
function makeMyObject<T>(obj: MyObject<T>): MyObject<T> {
    return obj;
}
```

Then when you type:

```typescript
export const a = makeMyObject({m│
//                              ^−−−− (cursor)
```

...it offers `myProp: unknown` as a completion choice:

[image]

Sometimes you have to resort to a do-nothing function in order to get the inference you want. :-| (I'd like to see a Java-esque `export const a: MyObject<> = {` thing that has the same effect, but as far as I know there isn'e one...)

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. I understand I can omit the type for `a` and `b` and have TS infer those types instead. However, if I do that, I now lose autocompletion when writing the module (i.e. I don't know that `myProp` is a valid property). Similarly, I don't want to pass an explicit type variable to `MyObject` because the whole point is to infer this type -- in this example, it's a simple scalar type but in practice this could be a very complex type that I don't want the library user to have to write out by hand.

Comment: @DanielRearden - As I said in the answer, autocompletion should work just fine in that case, and does in VSCode and the TypeScript playground. What are you using where it isn't? Perhaps it's a tooling issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer T.J. Like I tried to expand in the comment and my edit to the question, the issue here is not with autocompletion inside `index.ts` but inside, for example `moduleA`. In other words, I'd like to type `export const a = { m` and see `myProp` as a suggestion. The only way I know to do that, though, is to explicitly provide the type for `a` first.

Comment: It's my understanding that the type for `a` can either be explicitly defined or otherwise inferred from the literal value. If it's inferred, no autocompletion will be available.

Comment: Ah! Okay, sorry. I've updated the answer. I don't think you can get that inference without a function, I'm afraid, but a do-nothing function isn't expensive.

Comment: Ahhhhhh :facepalm: completely forgot we can do that. Thanks!